# ReDim multidimentional dynamic array

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have 2 listObject tables ([completeList] and [CatMarketPBI]) in a single workbook.
I read the val **CATID** from [completeList] and if matches with the **Row Label** in [CatMarketPBI], then I want to assign 16 values in an array.

After each matching ID, I redim the array for the next value, but when running the macro, the Array only gets the first matching values (from a single ID) and the others are not stored in the array.

ReDim seems to not work in my code.

```
    
Dim newCatUserMarkt() As Variant
Dim nbCat As Integer
ReDim newCatUserMarkt(nbCat,16)
' ReDim newCatUserMarkt(0 To nbCat, 16) also tried this one without more success

    nbCat = 0
    compList.Activate
    For r = 2 To lastRow
        searchCATID = Cells(r, [completeList[CATID]].Column)
        searchVal = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(searchCATID, [CatMarketPBI[Row Labels]], [CatMarketPBI[Markets]], 0)
        If searchVal <> 0 Then
            If Cells(r, [completeList[Use]].Column) <> "" Then
                ' Do nothing
            Else
                Cells(r, [completeList[Market]].Column) = searchVal
                Set rowCatSearch = [CatMarketPBI].Rows(WorksheetFunction.Match(searchCATID, [CatMarketPBI[Row Labels]], 0))
                CatMarkPBI.Activate
                
                
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 0) = r
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 1) = searchCATID
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 2) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[AT]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 3) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[AU]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 4) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[BE]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 5) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[CH]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 6) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[CH_FR]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 7) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[CH_IT]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 8) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[DE]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 9) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[ES]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 10) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[FR]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 11) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[GB]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 12) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[IT]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 13) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[LU]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 14) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[NL]].Column)
                newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 15) = Cells(rowCatSearch.Row, [CatMarketPBI[NZ]].Column)
                nbCat = nbCat + 1
                ReDim Preserve newCatUserMarkt(nbCat, 16)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
```

The first matching values are found with *r = 3*. In the Locals, with the value *r = 4*, I have a new match (the second in fact), I can see that the value *nbCat* has changed from 0 to 1 but has not been used for the next array entry (in orange)

[image]

Comment: With ReDim preserve it is only possible to change the size of the last dimension of an array (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement)

Comment: A workaround that I have adopted in many of my projects is to have a [Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object) of Arrays. Collections can be any size and each item can be any type. Adding arrays into a collection means you can essentially build a 2D array, row by row. When working with collections, the first item is 1, so the code to access the first item of the first array in the collection would be `MyCollection(1)(0)`

Comment: Thanks @Shrotter
I managed to register my array just by inverting the values in it and ReDim on the last entry.